# python configuration in pycharm should we need to change it every time

Tags: python, pycharm

I ran 'hello' file code get output then I created 'xy' file and ran and get the output of 'hello' file, I know it's because of the configuration but do we need to change its interpreter every time we create a new file? or is there any better way

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Right-click anywhere on your program code and click `Run Your Python Program`

I think you asked for this.